# resume search with full text index

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, optimization

I have a database structure where resume stored in document column in WHDocument table in database for each person. During skilled person search in application the persons skill is also searched for exclude/include keyword (eg developer) in document column(storing whole resume) of WHDocument table. Fulltext index also created in document column, still the performance is too slow while seleting data from document column with large volume of data in WHDocument Table(almost 1 million).Is it better to use some noSql database for storing resume and select person skill from noSql database where resume is stored or fulltext index in document column is sufficient for the purpose?
If NoSql is better option , how Can I use it to link to NoSql and display in UI ? ( need some detailed explanation or link).
Below query used to search data from document table in sql server RDBMS(with exluce include variable used for excuding/including a person with mentioned skill in resume)

```sql
SELECT npc.PersonId
FROM   dbo.WHDocument AS w
       INNER JOIN dbo.Document z ON  z.DocumentId = w.DocumentId
       INNER JOIN dbo.PersonDocument npc ON npc.DocumentId = w.DocumentId
WHERE  ( CONTAINS(w.Document, @IncludeWithoutAsterisk) OR @IncludeWithoutAsterisk = '""' ) 
      AND ( NOT CONTAINS(w.Document, @ExcludeWithoutAsterisk) OR @ExcludeWithoutAsterisk = '""' )
```

Comment: Please provide your table definitions, index definitions, and execution plan. We can't advise you without that information. FWIW, putting the data in a NoSQL database doesn't automatically make searching it faster or easier.